# 'WebElement' has no len() I could not fully understand the problem

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

This is my code, I do not understand why this code gives an error. thanks for your help.

```
<ipython-input-35-aae8cdac0da0> in <module>
     69 browser.switch_to.window(browser.window_handles[1])
     70 time.sleep(5)
---> 71 browser.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@name="emailOrPhone"]').send_keys(email)
     72 browser.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@name="fullName"]').send_keys(name1+name2)
     73 browser.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@name="username"]').send_keys("0."+nameu+".0")

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py
in send_keys(self, *value)
    476 
    477         self._execute(Command.SEND_KEYS_TO_ELEMENT,
--> 478                       {'text': "".join(keys_to_typing(value)),
    479                        'value': keys_to_typing(value)})
    480 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\utils.py in
keys_to_typing(value)
    148                 typing.append(val[i])
    149         else:
--> 150             for i in range(len(val)):
    151                 typing.append(val[i])
    152     return typing
```

**Error message is:**

```
TypeError: object of type 'WebElement' has no len()
```

Comment: what is the output if `print(val)`

Comment: for i in val: typing.append(i) would be more appropriate. If val was obtained with driver.find_elements. len() is used only on lists.

Comment: Update the question with your code trials.